# Cann`t deploy contract using pragma solidity 4.21 (after solidity 4.20)

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, events

I cant call me a pro at all. Rather newbie than pro, wishing to learn and develop. I`m sincerely asking you to help me.

I have the token and crowdsale contract (testing) which I deploy and initialize using `solidity ^0.4.20` without any issues. But in the `REMIX` I have an exclamation mark there like this:

`Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure function finalization() internal {
^
Spanning multiple lines.`

No matter of what it still works fine (include finalization step).

But when I try to compile it with `solidity ^0.4.21`

(after adding `emit` and some changes in `...............(this.balance);` to `...........(myAddress.balance);` with adding additional string above: `address myAddress = this;`) - to remove all exclamation marks (except `finalization()`)

Token deploys fine but the crowdsale contract gives me an error:

`"Error: gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"`

Seems that its not enought just to make this changes (above). Did I miss anything?.
+
Could this `finalization()` warning exclamation mark affect and breake everything in 4.21?

I saw people help each other here and it works very effective. So I decided to post my question as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Need the full code.

Comment: Please show your source code to be able to help.

Comment: This question is a mess! Consider positing the entire contract (or at least a "consecutive chunk") instead of those little fragments of code.

Comment: Remix has a default value of 3M gas, if your crowdsale is larger it will fail, in the "Run" tab there's a "Gas Limit" option that allows to set a larger value.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `address(this).balance` to cast `this` to the `address` type instead of adding one more variable.

Maybe this will help, if no - provide the full source of your contract please.